# Replace part of string with '()'

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace some country names which has '()' or numbers in the 'Country' column of a dataframe.
For Example 'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)' should be 'Bolivia'. 'Switzerland17' should be 'Switzerland'.

I am using the below code

```
df3['Country'] = df3['Country'].str.replace(r'[^(][\w]*[)]','')
df3['Country'] = df3['Country'].str.replace(r'[\d]*','')
```

Where am i am going wrong here ,can you help

Comment: as a general rule, try to include some code that can be executed right away. In this case, the input is missing in the snippet. Also, print your output, so that people can make a check against what you are getting.

Comment: Like this? `\([^()]*\)|\d+` https://regex101.com/r/0OTt87/1

Comment: ``r'[^(][\w]*[)]'`` -> `r'\([^\)]*\)'`

Comment: `df3['Country'].str.replace(r"\s*(?:\d+|\([^()]*\))","").str.strip()`

Comment: what's the input and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a single pass replacing the text between parenthesis or digits:

```
\s*(?:\([^()]*\)|\d+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\([^()]*\)|\d+` Match either from `(`.. till ..`)` or match 1+ digits
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y39i7I/1)

```
df3['Country'] = df3['Country'].str.replace(r'\s*(?:\([^()]*\)|\d+)', '')
```

Output

```
       Country
0      Bolivia
1  Switzerland
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```py
df3['Country'].str.replace(r"\s*(?:\d+|\([^()]*\))","").str.strip()
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wdlBWi/2). Details:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:\d+|\([^()]*\))` - either one or more digits, or `(`, then zero or more chars other than `(` and  `)`, then a `)`

The `.str.strip()` is necessary if the match happens to be at the start and is followed with whitespace.

See the Pandas test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Bolivia (Plurinational State of)','Switzerland17','(Republic of) Korea']})
>>> df3['Country'].str.replace(r"\s*(?:\d+|\([^()]*\))","").str.strip()
0        Bolivia
1    Switzerland
2          Korea
Name: Country, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I would using the following pattern: '([^)]*)|[\d.*]' the `|` character let's you use multiple patterns in a single line.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Bolivia (Plurinational State of)','Switzerland17']})
```

Original df:

```
    Country
0   Bolivia (Plurinational State of)
1   Switzerland17
```

Suggested code:

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace(r'\([^)]*\)|[\d.*]','',regex=True)
```

Outputs:

```
    Country
0   Bolivia
1   Switzerland
```